# What is the difference between the Load and Render objects in Devel?

Tags: debugging

When viewing a Node in the Devel tab, what are these different objects Load and Render? How and where would I have access to them in the theme layer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The "Load" tab shows the output of [node_load()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_load/7), while the "Render" tab shows the output of [node_view()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_view/7). In the first case, the output is a node object; in the second case, the output is an array as accepted by [drupal_render()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_render/7).

Comment: Note that in the render tab you have a row "#node" and if you try to open it you get a "(Recursion)". The load tab has the content of that node object.